# Using Generic Class Types in Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```
class Entity {
    id: number
}

class ChildEntity extends Entity {
    child_property: number;
}

class ChildEntity2 extends Entity {
    child_property_2: number;
}

class Data<T extends Entity> {
    protected entity: T
    static method() {
    }
}

class ChildData extends Data<ChildEntity> {
    childMethod() {
        this.entity.child_property = 1;
    }
}

class ChildData2 extends Data<ChildEntity2> {
    childMethod() {
        this.entity.child_property_2 = 1;
    }
}

function doStuffAndInstantiate(Input /* What should be the type here??? */ ) {
// function doStuffAndInstantiate<T extends Entity>(Input: new ()=> Data<T> ) { /* Error at Input.method() call: Property 'method' does not exist on type 'new () => Data '. */
// function doStuffAndInstantiate(Input: typeof Data ) { /* error at doStuffAndInstantiate(ChildData) call: 'ChildEntity' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Entity'. */
    Input.method();
    return new Data();
}

doStuffAndInstantiate(ChildData);
doStuffAndInstantiate(ChildData2);
```

What should be the type of `Input` argument of `doStuffAndInstantiate`? I've tried many ways with absolutely no success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new ()=> Data<T>` type fails, as this type definition does not include the statics of your `Data` class. `typeof Data` fails, because the `prototype` properties differ between `Data` and `ChildData`.

One approach is to exclude the `prototype` property and then add back in the `Data<T>` constraints.

```js
function doStuffAndInstantiate<
  T extends Entity,
  R extends (new () => Data<T>) & Omit<typeof Data, 'prototype'>
>(Input: R): Data<T> {
  Input.method();
  return new Data();
}
```

---

If your child classes do not override any static methods of the `Data` class, it would be cleaner to use `Data`'s methods directly:

```js
function doStuffAndInstantiate<T extends Entity>(Input: new () => Data<T>){
    Data.method();
    return new Input();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### What do the errors you got mean?

I think you're getting a little bit confused:

- `function doStuffAndInstantiate<T extends Entity>(Input: new ()=> Data<T>)`

Doesnt compile because it's misusing the keyword `new`. `new` in typescript is used to create instances of a class as you're doing in your function implementation. As far as my understanding goes, `new` doesn't make a lot of sense inside a type annotation (the type annotation of your parameter) (unless you can teach me something new :)!)

> Error at Input.method() call: Property 'method' does not exist on type 'new () => Data '

`() => Data` it's a type dictating:

*"A function with no parameters that returns an object from the class Data"*

So since it's a **function** it doesn't have any properties named `method` that are invokable. (From what you've explicitly provided in your sample code)

- `function doStuffAndInstantiate(Input: typeof Data )`

What you've just declared with this line is:

*"A function that takes one parameter named 'Input' which is a reference to the class Data and returns nothing"*

> error at doStuffAndInstantiate(ChildData) call: 'ChildEntity' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Entity'.

Which is true since ChildData nor ChildData2 are a reference to the class `Data`.

#### My attempt on providing a solution based on what's on the question on 26/07 at 10:46

I still have a hard time figuring out what you're trying to do. You're trying to call a static method from `Data` but you're passing in the class references from `ChildData` and `ChildData2` which **ARE NOT** related what-so-ever with `Data` since they just `extend Entity`.

As per now, what I can provide you with is the following:

```js
function doStuffAndInstantiate<T extends Entity>(): Data<T> {
  // Since it's a static method you don't need to pass a parameter to call it
  Entity.method()
  // We're getting the generic type from the function
  return new Data<T>();
}
```

Which you could just consume as:

```js
const childEntity = doStuffAndInstantiate<ChildEntity>(); // returns Data<ChildEntity>
const childEntity2 = doStuffAndInstantiate<ChildEntity2>(); // returns Data<ChildEntity2>
```

What I've just declared is:

*"A generic function that takes no parameters that returns an object of the class `Data` with the given generic type `T`"*

And that is as far as the compiler may go without any annotation or preprocessor magic that would search for a valid candidate that has a suitable constructor.

If you like to get direct instances of your subclasses `ChildData` and ChildData2`you'd need to`switch`or`if-elseif-else`through all the classes that you any be interested in returning. Since this would be done at runtime you can't properly type-annotate it because typescript won't let you use`T` as a value because it refers to a type (which don't exist when transpiled to JavaScript).

It'd look something like:

```js
function doStuffAndInstantiate(classOfSomething: unknown): any | null {

    switch(classOfSomething) {
        case ChildData2: 
            return new ChildData2();
        case ChildData: 
            return new ChildData();
        default: 
            return null;
    }
   

}
```

or you can just declare it as instantiable?

```
export type Abstract<T = any> = Function & { prototype: T };
export type Instantiable<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
export type Class<T = any> = Abstract<T> & Instantiable<T>;


function  doStuffAndInstantiate<E extends Entity, T extends Data<E>>(classOfSomething: Class<T> & { method: () => void }): T {
    classOfSomething.method();
    return new classOfSomething();
}
```

It's a tad hard to guess what you're looking for hehe

Comment: Ok, but what if the `method` is overridden in `ChildEntity` ? On that case I'd always use the `method` of base class instead of the child's one.

Comment: `Input.method()` will fail with `TS2339: Property 'method' does not exist on type 'Class<T>'. Property 'method' does not exist on type 'Abstract<T>'.` if I do this: `function doStuffAndInstantiate<E extends Entity, T extends Data<E>>(Input:Class<T> ) {`

Comment: Let me update the last solution provided. It's complaining it doesn't have `method` so basically we need to combine two types: like this `Class<T> & { method: () => void}`

Comment: This is what I'd like to avoid. To re-define all the static methods I'd like to use in the funciton :-/. In this case if I remove `method` from the class, typescript will see no error, althought I'm calling a non-existent method.

Comment: If you pass some class that doesn't have a `method` method will get you a compile-time error, so if you remove it from either one it won't compile anymore.

Comment: So every time I'd like to use another method (`method2()` or `method3()` etc...) I'll have to change the type as well...? It seems to be too much code duplication. I've added the bounty to get an answer that somehow solves this problem, because the already existing old answer already suggested to do this.

Comment: What is exactly that you want? Call all methods you add in the corresponding class that is being passed in?

Comment: If you want to **ensure** a class being passed in **has** a method you **need** to declare it so the compiler will warn you when you do something illegal. If you want to call all or static methods matching a certain predicate you can just loop through them with a for-statement that I can showcase to you. Another approach is just to declare `method` and from inside of it call all other static methods that you think are suitable.

Comment: I got the following error for `new classOfSomething`: `TS2351: This expression is not constructable.   Not all constituents of type 'Class<T> & { method: () => void; }' are constructable.     Type 'Function & { prototype: T; } & { method: () => void; }' has no construct signatures.`

Comment: Which TS config are you using? I can compile it on the typescript playground using 4.3.5

Comment: Now that I had some more time I have prepared a codepen for you: https://codepen.io/NanoSpicer/pen/LYyeKBQ

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to declare that you want an object that's callable with `new` and returns your `Data<T>` (`new () => Data<T>`), and also has a property called `method` that is a function that takes no arguments with an ignored return value (`() => void`).

Give this a try:

```js
function doStuffAndInstantiate<T extends Entity>(Input: { method(): void; new(): Data<T> }): Data<T> {
  Input.method();
  return new Input(); // You'll also want to instantiate "Input", not "Data" directly
}
```

Edit: Or, if you want to get more generic, you can produce a more accurate return type:

```js
function doStuffAndInstantiate<
  T extends Entity,
  U extends Data<T>,
  V extends { method(): void; new(): U },
  W = V extends { new(): infer W } ? W : never
>(Input: V): W {
  Input.method();
  return new Input() as unknown as W;
}

// TS is happy with this now
doStuffAndInstantiate(ChildData2).childMethod();
```

Comment: yes... but I would like my type to know about all the static types of `Input`. If I do this way, I'll have to change this type each time I add a new static method to `Input`.

Comment: What do you mean? There is no way for the compiler to magically know about types that are not declared, if you want to access a property of `Input` then you must somehow tell the compiler that it exists. Do you possibly mean that you want to return the actual type of `Input`? I've updated my answer to be "more generic", take a look. (Also, sorry for the slow response)

Comment: "There is no way for the compiler to magically know about types that are not declared" I can't understand why. `typeof Input` (my 2nd commented example) will know about all the static methods. But `ChildData` will be not assignable to it at the function call.